# ReactiveMongo 0.9: Joda Datetime Implicit Conversion for Macros.handler

Tags: mongodb, scala, jodatime, implicit-conversion

I have case class with joda Datetime field:

```
case DomainPositionData(domain: String, position: Int, change: Option[Int], date:DateTime)
```

Trying to use macro to generate reader&writer:

```
implicit val domPosFormat = Macros.handler[DomainPositionData]
```

I got:

```
Implicit org.joda.time.DateTime for 'value date' not found
```

But I haven't found info how to implement my own implicit convertor.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the [existing handlers](https://github.com/zenexity/ReactiveMongo/blob/0.9/bson/src/main/scala/handlers.scala#L104), you could try to create an implicit conversion like this (not tested):

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

implicit object BSONDateTimeHandler extends BSONHandler[BSONDateTime, DateTime] {
  def read(time: BSONDateTime) = new DateTime(time.value)
  def write(jdtime: DateTime) = BSONDateTime(jdtime.getMillis)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use new BSONReader & BSONWriter(having 2 type parameters in 0.9):

```
implicit object DatetimeReader extends BSONReader[BSONDateTime, DateTime]{
    def read(bson: BSONDateTime): DateTime = new DateTime(bson.value)
}

implicit object DatetimeWriter extends BSONWriter[DateTime, BSONDateTime]{
    def write(t: DateTime): BSONDateTime = BSONDateTime(t.getMillis)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For version 1.0.x

```
  implicit object DateTimeReader extends BSONReader[DateTime] {
    def readTry(bson: BSONValue): Try[DateTime] =  bson match {
      case time: BSONDateTime => Success(new DateTime(time.value))
      case _ => Failure(new IllegalArgumentException())
    }
  }

  implicit object DateTimeWriter extends BSONWriter[DateTime]{
    override def writeTry(t: DateTime): Try[BSONValue] = Try{
      BSONDateTime(t.getMillis)
    }
  }
```

or with val

```
  implicit val dateTimeReader: BSONReader[DateTime] = BSONReader[DateTime]{
    case  t: BSONDateTime => new DateTime(t.value)
  }

  implicit val dateTimeWriter: BSONWriter[DateTime] = BSONWriter[DateTime]{ time =>
    BSONDateTime(time.getMillis)
  }
```